# MVC Call method of controller by CSHTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple Web Application in C#.

In Index.cshtml file, I want to insert a button, and when I click on it, call a method of my Controller.

So I wrote this code:

```
<div class="row" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("action", "IndexController"))
            {

                <input type="submit" value="Create" />

            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my controller I'm build this code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string button)
{
  return View("TestView");
}
```

But if I try to click on button the application does not call method MyAction.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC convention requires the action name be used and the controller name minus "Controller" so, since your action method's name is "MyAction" and your controller's name is "IndexController", update the call like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Index"))
```

**Update based on comment:**

To send text to your action method to satisfy the `string button` parameter, you can include an input field in your form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Index"))
{
    <input type="text" name="button"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

**note that** the `name` attribute of the text field is "button" to **match** the `string button` parameter name.

- i'd suggest that another name other than button might be good, but whatever the name of your parameter, the input field that has a matching `name` attribute will supply the value to that parameter.

Comment: thanks you, I want also pass the parameter of InputText.
The user should to insert a value into TextBox, click on button, the method should to receive also this value.

Comment: @bircastri updated my answer to show how to send text to your action via a text field--the key is that the `name` attribute of your text field and the parameter name of the action must match